# Optimal tkinter file structure

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to divide my tkinter project into two files, let's call them GUI.py and backend.py.

GUI.py will contain all the widgets definitions, while backend.py will contain the functions binded to the widgets. The problem is that in GUI.py I need to import backend.py in order to have access to the funtions while defining a widget (e.g. `button = tk.Button(...,command=myFun)`, where myFun is defined in backend.py), while in backend.py I need to import GUI.py to access some eventual input boxes (e.g. `text = myBox.get()`, where myBox is defined in GUI.py). Beside the fact that this is kinda cumbersome, the code won't execute if written in this way.

What is the best way to divide the GUI from the backend?
Thank you!

Comment: If the backend needs to refer to specific widgets by name, then you in fact HAVEN'T divided the GUI from the backend at all.  Either pass the contents of that widget to a backend function when appropriate, or pass a callback function that will allow the backend to retrieve it when needed (without the backend having to have any specific knowledge about the widget).

Comment: Thank you, good point! So you are suggesting to do something like `button = tk.Button(...,command=guiFun)` where guiFun is defined inside GUI.py, and inside guiFun implement a call to a backend function passing the box widget as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that one file contains the starting point of the app. That's usually the GUI. It then imports what it needs, in this case the backend. If those imported functions or classes need to interact with the GUI, the GUI should pass what it needs to those functions or classes.

For example, this shows how GUI is responsible for creating the backend, and then uses the instance in order to call the backend functions. It also passes itself to the backend so that it can refer to the GUI.

### GUI.py

```
from backend import Backend

class GUI():
    def __init__():
        self.backend = Backend(self)
        ...
        self.button = tk.Button(..., command=self.backend.myFun)
        ...
```

### backend.py

```
class Backend():
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui
        ...
    def update_ui(self):
        self.gui.button.configure(state="disabled")
```

There are further enhancements you can make, but this shows the general pattern: objects that need call functions in other objects need to create or be given references to the other objects.

Comment: Thank you, this will help me clear things up!